# How to shrink-wrap a css grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

Assuming the following grid layout:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some  more text here as well thanks</span>
</div>
```

I would like to 'shrink-wrap' the grid items so that

1) the maximum width of the grid will only be as wide as the content, but

2) if there's not enough room for the content - the items will wrap accordingly.

In the above demo, the **first** constraint fails - the grid columns stretch to fit their respective content and all the *extra* viewport width is split equally (added) between the columns.

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/LOLpmW?editors=1100) - (Resize to see what I'm talking about)

I've tried a few approaches to fix this, but they all 'shrink-wrap' the grid items as apposed to the actual grid itself:

1) Set `max-content` as the track length instead of `auto`

```
grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px; 
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

2) Set `justify-content: flex-start;` on the grid container

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

3) Add a bogus 3rd column which fills the remaining viewport width with an empty third column:

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px; 
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

So how would I 'shrink-wrap' the grid?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `display: grid` on an element causes it to generate a **block-level** grid container box.

This is what causes the grid to fill the viewport width and stretch the items accordingly.

That being the case, we can stop the grid from stretching by setting one of the following on the grid container:

1) `display: inline-grid`;

```css
div {
  display: inline-grid; /* <-- modified */
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

2) `float: left; /* or right */`

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  float: left; /* <-- added */
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

3) `position: absolute;`

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  position: absolute; /* <--- added */
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px;
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, we could set `width: fit-content` on grid container.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-row-gap: 1em;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin: 50px; 
  width: fit-content; /* <-- added */
}
h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  margin: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: pink;
}
h3, span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
span + span {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>1. A heading here</h3>
  <span>some text here</span>
  <span>some text here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say that `width: fit-content` should be the solution (since we are talking about the modern layout mechanism) and the other options should be listed under "alternatively", e.g. as possible fallbacks :)